# laravel eloquent relation one to many returns null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship, eloquent

The product data always return null when i get the incoming_goods data (belongsTo).

Here is my Product Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Product extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $guarded = [
        'id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at',
    ];

    public function transaction_details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction_detail');
    }

    public function incoming_goods()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Incoming_good');
    }       
}
```

Here is my Incoming_good Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Incoming_good extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [
        'id', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
    ];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }       
}
```

And here is my migration of that two table:

products table Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 50);
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->integer('stock')->nullable();
            $table->integer('available');
            $table->string('image1', 190)->nullable();
            $table->string('image2', 190)->nullable();
            $table->string('image3', 190)->nullable();
            $table->string('image4', 190)->nullable();
            $table->string('image5', 190)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

incoming_goods migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTableIncomingGoods extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('incoming_goods', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('product_id');
            $table->integer('stock');
            $table->text('note')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('incoming_goods');
    }
}
```

Here is my code to show incomong_goods data and product (relation belongsTo):

```
$data = Incoming_good::select('id', 'stock', 'note', 'created_at')->with('product')->get();
```

I've try to use alies, but still it return the product data null. Hope you can help me :)

Comment: Please add the code for the query itself

Comment: You have to specify what fields in related models are foreign key for your main model.

Comment: Any example? @Grynets

Comment: Show the controller code where did you get the product !!

Comment: Sorry for that. I've edited my question @Maraboc

Comment: It's because of the table names... Laravel treats tables named Something1_Something2 as pivot table between Something1 and Something2

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for what should i do? @AlekseiMaide

Comment: Try to add `$table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('product_id')
      ->references('id')->on('products')
      ->onDelete('cascade');` then refresh your database and test again.

Comment: I've try to use foreign in my migration table, exactly same like that, but still not works @Maraboc

Comment: $this->hasMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id'); (random example from laravel docs), the function has more parameters which are table name, and primary keys... Since eloquent is confused by the "_" you are supposed to name those params. explicitly.

Comment: Still null @AlekseiMaide

Comment: Idk then, maybe try Incoming_good::product()->first();

Comment: `return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_id');` try this in Incoming_goods class

Comment: Still null @sebbz . I try to use this $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'id'); and it's work, but the problem is when there is the same product_id value (more than one) then it only work for the first data of that same product_id

Comment: Also check if `Incoming_good::select('id', 'stock', 'note', 'created_at')` there should be added also 'product_id'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to match up the eager loaded `Product`s with the `Incoming_good`s, Laravel needs the foreign key to be selected. Since you did not include the foreign key (`product_id`) in the select list, Laravel can't match up the related records after retrieving them. So, all your `product` relationships will be empty. Add in the foreign key to the select list, and you should be good.

```
$data = Incoming_good::select('id', 'product_id', 'stock', 'note', 'created_at')
    ->with('product')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Wow that's work! l'm really embarassed know the solution is that simple :'v btw thanks a lot